# Bootstrap modal event "shown.bs.modal" doesn't fire when declared in iframe

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ik have created and initialized a Bootstrap modal in the parent document, and the "shown.bs.modal" event is declared in an iframe on document ready. The parent and iframe documents are both on the same domain. The problem is that this event doesn't fire when the modal is opened. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Modal html in parent document:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header"><h4>Title</h4></div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery in parent document:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modalTrigger').on('click.openModal', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var trigger = $(this);
        var modal = top.$('#modal');

        modal.modal('show');
    });
});
```

jQuery in iframe:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modal = $('#modal', window.top.document); // Selects the right element in the parent window
    modal.on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        console.log('test'); // Doesn't fire
    });
});
```

I'm using jQuery 1.11.2 and Bootstrap 3.

Comment: Can you post any additional supporting code?

Comment: I have just added more code.

Comment: Just to clarify, your modal shows up but the event does not fire, correct?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to iframes, you are basically interacting with 2 different pages(maybe from two different domains). So when you fire an event in the iframe, it would trigger the event in that iframe alone, not the main document. The reason why it is not working might be because the browser does not allow it.

A work around would be to use `Jquery postMessage` which allows you to communicate with the two pages. So basically, what you need to do is when an event is fired in the main document, send a `postMessage` to the iframe. Receive the `postMessage` in the iframe and then show the model in the iframe.

You should check this example out : http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/

Edit/Update:

Another way to do this is by using a `getScript` instead of using a iframe. The code will go something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.modalTrigger').on('click.openModal', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var trigger = $(this);
    var modal = top.$('#modal');
    $.getScript("test.js",function(){
      modal.modal('show');
    });
  });
});
```

Test.js

```
var modal = $('#modal', window.top.document);
console.log('test');// Write a event you want to keep on the modal
```

Going for this approach, you might be able to acheive the functionality that you desire(based on the comments). When you click on the button that triggers the modal, it will call the $.getScript, and will execute a set of commands (can be used to create addition events). After it is successfully executed, it will show the model with the updated events.

Comment: I'm not sure if I can use postMessage here. In this case, an event (shown.bs.modal) is triggered by Bootstrap in the parent window, which is also the location of the modal. What I'm trying to do is overriding this event in the parent document from the iframe.

Comment: @Hans I have a question, when the modal is shown in the parent window, the iframe should do something??

Comment: Yes, the iframe should create an event on a button in the modal footer. I only defined one modal in the parent, and the iframe sets the event on the modal button with the right parameters. I didn't include this code because it's out of scope for this question.

Comment: @Hans If that is the case, I would suggest you to go for a direct approach instead of using the iframe approach, but if you are persistent on only using the iframe approach, then postMessage would be the appropriate method to go for. You can send postMessage from the parent to iframe, create the events necessary on the model, and then send another postMessage from the iframe to the parent and then show the model.

Comment: @Hans But if you want to do a direct approach, then you can just call script using $.getScript() right before the `modal.modal('show')` which would handle what type of events you want create on the modal and then show the modal after its is executed successfully.